# stress-ng: Simulate specific cpu percentages

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, stress-testing

Linux environment: Debian, Ubuntu, Centos

**Goal:**
Test monitoring program that set alarms and trigger different alarms at different cpu percentages.
ex: (30-50%), (51-70%) and >90%

So I need a cpu stresser that can simulate specific cpu percentage per core.
**stress-mg** looks like the most advanced.

According to its documentation http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/ it is possible to set load values between 0 and 100%:

> -l P  --cpu-load P    load CPU by P %, 0=sleep, 100=full load (see -c)

```
stress-ng -c 1 -p 30
```

> stress-ng: info: [12650] dispatching hogs: 0
>   I/O-Sync, 1 CPU, 0 VM-mmap, 0 HDD-Write, 0 Fork, 0 Context-switch, 30
>   Pipe, 0 Cache, 0 Socket, 0 Yield, 0 Fallocate, 0 Flock, 0 Affinity, 0
>   Timer, 0 Dentry, 0 Urandom, 0 Float, 0 Int, 0 Semaphore, 0 Open, 0
>   SigQueue, 0 Poll

**Undesired result:**
But it doesn't seem to work, aLL cores are hogged at 100%

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I designed stress-ng so that one can specify 0 for the number of stressor processes to match the number of on-line CPUs, so to load each cpu at say 40%, use

stress-ng -c 0 -l 40

Answer (score 6):

I should have used **-l option**

1. Looks like **-c 1** distribute the load between all cores. Not exactly 80/4 per core, I guess because the host already runing some stuff.

   stress-ng -c 1 -l 80

[image]

2. and **-c 4** simulate the load on each core

   stress-ng -c 4 -l 80

[image]

For more about stress-ng:
[assembly_stress-testing-real-time-systems-with-stress-ng_optimizing-rhel8-for-real-time-for-low-latency-operation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/8/html/optimizing_rhel_8_for_real_time_for_low_latency_operation/assembly_stress-testing-real-time-systems-with-stress-ng_optimizing-rhel8-for-real-time-for-low-latency-operation#proc_generating-a-virtual-memory-pressure_assembly_stress-testing-real-time-systems-with-stress-ng)

Comment: Along with the CPU if I want to bump the memory 50% how to do it ?

Comment: Look at the options: -vm <2> and --vm-bytes <1G>